# Python BeautifulSoup - Changing tag name and searching for string via string=re.compile

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I’m working on an HTML Cleaner/Modifier but I’m running into an issue when trying to change an element’s tag from "p" to "li". I’m searching for lines in the HTML input that have specific string contents via the Regular Expressions function “re.compile”. I am able to clean out the unwanted tags and tag attributes beforehand, but I can’t get it to change the tag name to a different one that I specify.

Example Input (I’ll be working with multiple lines of HTML text at the same time):

```
<p align="left">Extra string text<strong><span style="font-family: Arial,Arial; font-size: 10px; color: #343d47;">FOO:</span></strong> <span style="font-family: Arial,Arial; font-size: 10px; color: #343d47;">Additional extra string text</span></p>
<p align="left">Extra string text<strong><span style="font-family: Arial,Arial; font-size: 10px; color: #343d47;">BAR:</span></strong> <span style="font-family: Arial,Arial; font-size: 10px; color: #343d47;">Additional extra string text</span></p>
```

Here’s my code that “cleans” the HTML:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re

    inputdata = input("")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(inputdata, "html.parser")      

    def cleaner(soup):
        for p_tag in soup.find_all("p"):
            del p_tag["align"]
        for span_tag in soup.find_all("span"):        
            span_tag.unwrap()
        for li in soup.find_all("p", string=re.compile("FOO:")):   
            li.name = "li"
        return soup
   print(cleaner(soup))
```

I want the code output to look like this:

```
<li>Extra string text<strong>FOO:</strong> Additional extra string text</li>
<p>Extra string text<strong>BAR:</strong> Additional extra string text</p>
```

But it instead comes out without changing the "p" tag to a "li" tag. Like this:

```
<p>Extra string text<strong>FOO:</strong> Additional extra string text</p>
<p>Extra string text<strong>BAR:</strong> Additional extra string text</p>
```

It basically ignores the line of code that I created and devoted to changing the "p" tag with the “FOO:” string contents. Any idea why my “for” loop for this isn’t working?

Comment: Does your `for li in soup.find_all("p", string=re.compile("FOO:")):` loop match any tags? (Insert a debug print statement.) I'm not sure whether `string=` does partial matches and whether it matches text in nested tags (ie the `strong` tag).

Comment: I do actually think that the issue has to do with the fact that "FOO:" is nested within the "strong" tag - the code works without issue if I wanted to change the "strong" tags instead. Like this "<p>Extra string text<strong>FOO:</strong> Additional extra string text</p>" would be changed to this "<p>Extra string text<li>FOO:</li> Additional extra string text</p>" if I changed the "for" loop to this `for li in soup.find_all("strong", string=re.compile("FOO:")):`

Comment: @JoeP I do actually think that the issue has to do with the fact that `FOO:` is nested within the `strong` tag - the code works without issue if I wanted to change the `strong` tags instead. Like this `<p>Extra string text<strong>FOO:</strong> Additional extra string text</p>` would be changed to this `<p>Extra string text<li>FOO:</li> Additional extra string text</p>` if I changed the "for" loop to this `for li in soup.find_all("strong", string=re.compile("FOO:")):`

Comment: Yes - I don't know of a simple way to select based on tag name _and_ text nested inside subtags. You may have to iterate over `p` tags and then test the text. Alternatively use `XPath` expressions, which are supported by `lxml` - you can use it directly or set it as the parser for BeautifulSoup

Comment: I'll take a look. Thank you for your help!